# how to force the browser to run the javascript every time it called

Tags: javascript, php, html

Dears 
 I called a javascript function on onload body

```
<body onload="loadLeads()">
```

This function loads a leads information from database and display it in a table. 
The problem is when the user press on delete button to delete a lead from the table. the function runs correctly and delete the lead from the database. BUT although the deletelead function relaoad the page which calls loadLeads() on load the page which should display the new leads without the deleted one. BUT the deleted one display again! although it deleted from the database!! 
how can I run it correctly?? 
I should delete the cache of the browser each time to force the code runs correctly!! 
how can I do it please?

this is the javascript code for delete

```
function deleteLead(id)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "deletelead.php?id="+id, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This is the script calling in the HTML

```
 <script src="https://example.net/js/loadLeads.js?version=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '"\><\/script>'"></script>
```

This is the loadleads function javascript

```
function loadLeads()
{
     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            {
                 LeadsInfo = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                 LeadsInfoCount = LeadsInfo.length;
                DrawLeadsTable();

            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "LoadLeads.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This is the LoadLeads.php

```
<?php

     require "conn.php";


    $SelectSQL = "SELECT * FROM leads";
    $result = $conn->query($SelectSQL);
    $ECount = $result->num_rows; 

    if ($ECount != 0 )
    {

    $FinalArr = array(); 
    $count =0;  
        while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
                $id = $row1["id"];
                $name = $row1["name"];
                $email = $row1["email"];
                $mob = $row1["mob"];
                $country = $row1["country"];
                $comefrom = $row1["comefrom"];              
                $time = $row1["time"];
$qulified = $row1["qulified"];  
$landingpage = $row1["landingpage"];                
                $myArr = array($id,$name,$email, $mob,$country,$comefrom,$time,$qulified,$landingpage);
                    $FinalArr[$count] = array(); 
                    $FinalArr[$count] = $myArr; 
                    $count++;
                    $UserData = json_encode($FinalArr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }
    }


mysqli_close($conn);


echo $UserData;
?>
```

Comment: well sounds like you are not setting the correct caching headers on your get request

Comment: A request that deletes something _must not_ be a GET request.

Comment: When the page reloads, it the JS src doesn't change. Browser will use a cached copy of the JS and other resources as well when possible. You can overcome this by appending a random string the URL. I.e. don't reload but replace the location with the random bit always changing.

Comment: are you using IE? because it often cashes more things than it should

Comment: @mareful thank you for your reply. but how can I do it ?

Comment: @MajidLaissi no I tried opera and firebox even chrome

Comment: @Slaks so Should I user POST ?

Comment: please edit your post and add the function you call to get the infos from the db

Comment: Yes, or use DELETE.

Comment: @MajidLaissi Done

Comment: @Slaks Thank you I'll modify it

Comment: @marekful sorry I can't understand how can I do it ?

Comment: @SLaks, that is not true. I might better be DELETE but it _may_ be a GET request. Must is a too strong word here... Besides you didn't answer the question. Actually, no one seems to have realised what the OP's problem was in this particular case, i.e. dong `location.reload()` which reloads with cache and doesn't realise the changes the AJAX did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before the xmlhttp.send();

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```

Comment: That header applies to the response, not the request.

Comment: @NawedKhan THAAAAANK YOOOOU VERY MUCH, It finally workss